# Codeigniter installed at subdirectory showing 404 error

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, http-status-code-404, subdirectory

I have installed two codeigniter in my server. One is the root of the domain and for second I've creates one new folder and installed second codeigniter there. When I am trying to access the folder, it shows error 404.

Comment: Without further information from your side, there is not much we can do to help. Please add some info.

Comment: One main website is working fine but the sub folder website not working.

Comment: That tells us next to nothing... What have you actually got setup?

Answer (score 0):

You should define base url for sub directory in your config

You can get Idea from following example code

$config['base_url'] = http://example.com/sub;

Comment: I've tried this is not working. I've put the default welcome controller and its working but when I am trying with other controllers that is showing the same error. I don't know why this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Set you default base url for subdirectory

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://www.example.com/sub/"
```

Open config.php and do following replaces

```
$config['uri_protocol'] ="AUTO"
```

by

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

This code run all sub directory. Hope this will help you!.